# Можно ли ввести на сайте функцию «черный список»?

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено

Недавно на сайте «Большой вопрос» я хотела дать ответ, но система сообщила:  **«Вы не можете отвечать на вопрос, так как его автор поместил Вас в черный список».**

Давным-давно я ничего не пишу там в комментариях  и автора, разумеется, не помню. Но чем-то я  его обидела, и система напомнила мне, что надо быть вежливым.

Конечно, запрещать отвечать на вопросы – это уже чересчур, другое дело – комментарии. **Я, к примеру, не хотела бы, чтобы мои вопросы и ответы комментировали люди, проявившие по отношению ко мне явную недружественность и неуважение.**

На сайте «Большой вопрос», к примеру,   для этого не требуется вмешательство модератора, всё делается автоматически, объективно и беспристрастно.

Если эту функцию нельзя или не имеет смысла вводить для всех, то **я прошу у руководства форума личной защиты для себя,** так как чаще всего именно у меня возникают подобные проблемы, а в последнее время это происходит постоянно (сигнал «тревога» мало помогает, он не кажется мне эффективным).

Я много отвечаю, и посетители форума часто выражают мне свою благодарность.  А вот постоянные участники (я имею в виду **только двух-трех человек**) могут написать  мне такие, к примеру,  отзывы: ***«эт-та что?» или «ваш ответ никакой».***

**Последний случай** произвел на меня особенное впечатление, так как похож на преднамеренную провокацию. Участник  (7 месяцев работы на сайте, репутация — 360) вдруг вмешивается в комментарии, поправляет меня небрежно-менторским тоном, причем совершенно необоснованно и не у места (до этого мы ни разу не общались лично), а потом милостиво «прощает» мне эту небольшую «ошибку» — камнями меня за нее не закидают. [«Казалось» — в конкретном предложении. Пунктуация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450455/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**Так со мной еще ни разу не разговаривали.**

Я не знаю, как модераторы отреагировали на мое обращение, получил ли участник какое-либо замечание — ко мне не поступает такая информация. Мне не надо извинений от таких людей, я просто не хочу с ними общаться и получать от них комментарии.

**Это моя личная просьба, которую я прошу рассмотреть.**

Answer (score 1):

**Вы хотите Его попросить?** Но я уже просила Его об этом.  Ведь  несогласие с ответом необязательно выражать в комментарии, достаточно дать свой альтернативный ответ (короче говоря, вполне можно обойтись без личных контактов). Да вот только Он не согласился, это не Его метод.  **Так неэффектно, неинтересно  – другими словами, никакого удовольствия.**

**В этой ситуации можно вспомнить такой детский стишок**: «Трудно жить на свете пионеру Пете, бьёт его по р…е пионер Серёжа».  Стих непритязательный, и рифма смешная, но вот содержание не так забавно.

**Внешне всё бывает очень благопристойно и правильно!**  Вот и дети уважают друг друга, даже называют вежливо  – не Петька, не Серёжка.  А что у одного пионера проблемы весьма серьезные, то до этого никому и дела нет.

Вот и за моё предложение никто не проголосовал и  даже комментария не оставил. **А зачем? Ведь это практически никого не касается.**

Я тоже за правильное,  демократичное и свободное общество, я тоже против силового решения проблем, но это не значит, что  **отдельный человек не имеет право на защиту.**  Получается, что общество – это всё, а индивидуальные интересы ничего не значат?

**Представьте, что это вы хотите кого-то удалить с форума (любого человека).**  У него высокий рейтинг? Это не проблема, для того чтобы комментировать и голосовать, вам-то много баллов не требуется. Минусовка? В принципе это не запрещается, даже объяснять многого не надо, но уж слишком заметно.

Можно просто **на каждый его ответ добавлять несколько комментариев.** И даже риторику оскорбительную применять необязательно  – достаточно просто выражать сомнения, просить привести примеры, потом сомневаться в приведенных примерах и т.д. Негативное отношение при этом будет выражаться подтекстом.

**В конце концов такое давление непременно приведет к желаемому результату**, а вы будете полностью удовлетворены: вы  поставили задачу и вы ее выполнили.  **Поэтому вы распоряжаетесь здесь** (пусть даже ваша репутация не больше сотни баллов), а демократичное и свободное общество на самом деле **подчиняется вашим  желаниям.**

**Этот  пример (вполне реальный) о чём-нибудь говорит?**

А это последний "шедевр" от N (просьба, как видно, отклонена): ***Ну, скопировали сюда две явные ошибки. И зачем?.. Называется это "синдром повышенной грамотности", когда всюду хочется ставить запятые.***

["В свете последних событий" обособляется?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452490/%D0%92-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)

"Грамотный" человек уверен, что **обособляются только вводные слова, но нет обособленных обстоятельств** (Розенталь "отдыхает"). При этом он  ставит мне минус за ответ, а вот его ответ, конечно ж, само совершенство: "Да нет, не обособляется. Это не вводное сочетание". Как говорится, без комментариев. Вероятно, это наш **новый "стандарт качества".** Почему не вводное – неизвестно, почему в этом случае не обособляется – непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Sharon, не думаю, что введение черного списка на нашем сайте возможно: мы стремимся создать такое сообщество, которое бы порождало не распри, а то, что можно огрубляя назвать «знанием».

Предлагаю вам (и любым другим участникам) писать о проблемах, требующих особого внимания, напрямую в чат — https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/, отмечая меня (@Aer) или других модераторов в начале сообщения. Хотя уверяю, что вы ошибаетесь насчет эффективности тревог.

Комментарии типа *эт-та что?* или *ваш ответ никакой* — совершенно неуместны. Отмечайте их тревогой, и они будут удалены.

Если я правильно понял, о каком участнике речь, то веских оснований его наказывать нет: нужно пояснить, как работает наш сайт, и призвать к здравому диалогу. Более того, обращаю ваше внимание на то, что участник извинился за свое, может быть, «необычное» поведение.

Comment: Я сожалею, что нельзя, потому что вопрос о нежелательных контактах решался бы тогда легко и просто. Участник за свое поведение сначала получит первое предупреждение, потом второе, третье, потом самое последнее, а я за это время получу целый комплекс негативных эмоций и желание прекратить работу на форуме. А при наличии черного списка нет контактов - нет проблем.

Comment: @Sharon если участник совершил что-то серьезное, нет никаких предупреждений. Он сразу получает наказание. Так что вы ошибаетесь насчет механизма модерации.

Comment: У нас могут быть разные понятия о серьезности нарушений, а черный список позволил бы мне самой решать, насколько они серьезны. Но если это невозможно, то я еще раз обращаюсь с просьбой: решите эту проблему как-нибудь еще. Можно просто довести до сведения участника, что его комментарии в отношении определенного лица запрещены, если нельзя эту функцию сделать автоматической.

Comment: @Sharon укажите конкретный случай, который сейчас требует нашего внимания.

Comment: Сейчас - нет случаев, сейчас мир, покой и тишина. Хорошо,  если бы всегда  так было.

Comment: Указываю конкретный случай, который требует Вашего внимания.  Я не хочу получать комментарии от известного Вам лица. Я бы хотела на форуме отвечать на вопросы, а не на его комментарии, которые я получаю ежедневно на каждый свой ответ. Вот последний: Вы разве не чувствуете, что это НЕ сравнительный оборот?https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452401/Запятая-перед-словно/452403?noredirect=1#comment462498_452403

Comment: Вы Скажете, что в нем нет ничего оскорбительного? В данном случае нет, но я не хочу общаться с ним на уровне "вы чувствуете или нет". Три года бесконечных придирок и приставаний меня утомили чисто эмоционально. Мне нужен маленький индивидуальный "черный список" на одного человека, неужели мне никак нельзя помочь? Если нет необходимости вводить черный список вообще, то сделайте исключение для меня лично. Это моя просьба к руководству сайта.

Comment: Я всегда отвечаю на комментарии, когда люди задают вопросы,  действительно желая в них разобраться. В этом случае я стараюсь дать подробные объяснения,  делюсь свои знаниями, насколько это возможно.  Но участника N полезная информация не интересует, все его комментарии делаются с единственной целью -  негативно отозваться обо мне и о моих ответах.

Comment: @Sharon мы попросим участника не писать вам.

Comment: Спасибо. Когда он согласится, пожалуйста, сообщите мне об этом. Сегодня 31 мая 2019 года.